# what do i use to attach an ikea table top to storage facilities. links attached

Tags: screws, table

I want to attach these -

[image: Algot shelves]

[Ikea Algot](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/storage-furniture/storage-systems/algot-frame-6-mesh-baskets-top-shelf-white-spr-59183917/)

to this -

[image: Bekant table top]

[Bekant table top](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/desks/office-desks/bekant-table-top-white-art-00253238/)

what would be the best way?

Comment: You want to attach those to that where ? on the top, on the bottom, on the side, with the frame, without the frame.????

Answer (score 2):

There's no single best method - it depends on your subjective opinion and your personal criteria for best (price, durability, aesthetic, ease of cleaning, ...)

Pipe clips

[image: Copper 15mm pipe-clip]